# How to link a ComboBox with Database values

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How do I link a `ComboBox` with Database values? I get an error message when trying the below code:

```
Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
Try
    tilkobling.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "select * from g_oops_22.minsideNy"
    Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, tilkobling)
    READER = Command.ExecuteReader

    While READER.Read
        Dim blodLokasjon = READER.GetString("blodgivninglokasjon")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(blodLokasjon)
    End While

    tilkobling.Close()
```

Comment: please also include the content of error message in your question

Comment: `Dim dt As New DataTable`...`dt.Load(Command.ExecuteReader)`...`ComboBox1.DataSource = dt`. You'll then need to set the `.DisplayMember` and .`ValueMember` properties. That being said, if you are getting errors, it's a lot easier to help if you provide such errors.